# Visio - How to reduce size of giant flow chart

Tags: diagram, visio, flowchart

In my current company I have a huge flow chart that needs to be expanded even more.

We have these so called **Procs** that are used within the Mainframe

so say I have this

```
+--------+
| PH50075|
|        |
|        |
+--------+
```

but this **PH50075** needs to be breakdown even more because it executes a series of programs and each one of them have a bunch of inputs and outputs.

So say PH50075 executes programs IEBGNER, ICEMAN and a bunch of other ones each having 7 inputs and 10 outputs which have to be described in each one of them, being that every program has its own **box**.
You can say its a reasonable amount but now imagine that I have 22 **Procs** like that, it'd turn out to be a giant and un-readable flow for printing or visualizing.

Is there a known way that I can make it smaller? Either by placing a hyperlink(to another page containing its contents) on **PH50075** or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You can create a page for each PROC, and then hyperlink from your main page to the subordinate page. So, using your figures, you could have one main page and 22 subordinate pages. Depending on the complexity, these subordinate pages could be broken down in the same way.

There are addins for Visio (commercial products) that would do this for you. I work in the business process mapping space and the add-in I have used does this thing as part of business as usual.